# Unexpected value of expression involving assignment

Tags: apl, dyalog

I saw this logic and wonder why the result is one rather than zero:

```
      P ← 1 1 0
      Q ← 0 0 1
      ∨/ P ∧← Q
1
```

On the other hand the following results in zero:

```
      P ← 1 1 0
      Q ← 0 0 1
      ∨/ P ← P ∧ Q
0
```

I'm using Dyalog APL 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of *any* assignment is the value to the right of the assignment arrow, so `P ∧← Q` returns `Q` while `P ← P ∧ Q` returns `P ∧ Q` which is also the new value assigned to `P`, per [the documentation](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Primitive%20Operators/Assignment%20Modified.htm):

> #### Assignment (Modified)   `{R}←Xf←Y`
>
> (…)
>
> `R` is the “pass-through” value, that is, the value of `Y`.  If the result of the derived function is not assigned or used, there is no explicit  result.

To get the performance benefit of in-place modification, while using the new value inline, you can write `∨/ P ⊣ P ∧← Q`